# C: Problems with Reversing a linked list

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to create a linked list(a node), then reverse it. The linked list contains data and the address of the next.

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

Firstly, I create the linked list.

```
struct node *Insert_value(int dataInput,node* head)
{
    node *new_node=NULL;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node -> next = head;
    new_node -> data = dataInput;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}
```

After that, i create a function to print these data. (i called it PrintNode)

```
    while(head!= NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",head->data);
            head= head->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Finally, a function created to reverse the linked list.

```
struct node* Reversing(node **head)
{
    node *current, *previous, *first;
    current = previous = first = *head;

    first = first->next->next;
    current = current->next;
    previous ->next = NULL;
    current->next = previous;

    while(first != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = first;
        first = first -> next;
        previous->next = current;
    }

    return current;
}
```

It's my full program.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

struct node *Insert_value(int dataInput,node* head);
struct node * Reversing(node **head);
void PrintNode(node *head);

main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int i=0,dataInput;
    while(i!=5)
    {
        printf("input your elements: ");
        scanf("%d",&dataInput);
        head = Insert_value(dataInput,head);
        i++;
    }
    PrintNode(head);
    head = Reversing(&head); 
    PrintNode(head);


}               

struct node *Insert_value(int dataInput,node* head)
{
    node *new_node=NULL;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node -> next = head;
    new_node -> data = dataInput;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}

struct node* Reversing(node **head)
{
    node *current, *previous, *first;
    current = previous = first = *head;

    first = first->next->next;
    current = current->next;
    previous ->next = NULL;
    current->next = previous;

    while(first != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = first;
        first = first -> next;
        previous->next = current;
    }

    return current;
}

void PrintNode(node* head)
{
    while(head!= NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",head->data);
            head= head->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

After debugging lots of times, I know that these functions are fine. However, after the reverse function, the address of the next node of the `head` variable is NULL. Can you explain and give me some pieces of advice?

Comment: Don't forget to `free` your list, e.g. `while (head != NULL) { node *victim = head; head = head->next; free (victim); }`

Answer (score 3):

The one line change that will solve your problem will be (you visualized it a bit wrong).

```
current->next =previous;
```

in place of

```
previous->next = current;
```

---

Your code will blowup for single element linked list. Add a proper check for that in the function `Reversing()`. In case there is single element `first->next` will be `NULL`. But you wrote `first->next->next` which will be undefined behavior in case `first->next` is `NULL`.

---

In earlier case you were just creating a linked list in `Reversing()` with the links unchanged but `head` was pointing to the last node. So the `next` of it was `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Modify `Reversing` such that new nodes are appended at the end. When going through the list, you need to save the next node ahead of time (`node *next = current->next`)

```
struct node* Reversing(node **head)
{
    node *current = *head;
    node *reverse = NULL;

    while(current)
    {
        node *next = current->next;

        if(!reverse)
        {
            reverse = current;
            reverse->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = reverse;
        }
        reverse = current;

        current = next;
    }

    return reverse;
}
```